# redirect all .txt files at the root dir to 404 (Except robots.txt)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to configure my .htaccess to redirect all txt files **at the root dir** to 404 Error. (Except robots.txt)

I tried using
`RedirectMatch 404 [^robots]\.txt$`
But it redirects also txt files on my sub directories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots.real [L]
RewriteRule ^/[^/]*\.txt$ /404.php [L]
```

where `404.php` is a document returning 404 and `robots.real` is the name of your `robots.txt`.

Omit the first `ErrorDocument` statement if you don't want to design your own error message page, but it is usually nice to have one, because you can then have it in your own style, as well as perform logic in it to catch misspellings and so on.

Come to think of it, you probably don't need to create a 404 page at all. If you use mod_rewrite to have all txt documents fetch a non-existent page instead, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^/[^/]*\.txt$ a-page-that-does-not-exist.html [L]
```

The reason why your example in the question fails is because the regular expression `[^robots]\.txt$` matches everything that ends in a character other than r,o,b,t,s followed by `.txt`.
By adding `^/` before that, you will match all one-letter (except robts) .txt files in the root.

The `^` in the beginning of the regular expression means the beginning of the URI, and inside the brackets it means "not". Brackets mean "one of the characters inside".

If you add a `*`-sign to the regexp, it means zero-or-more occurrences of whats immediately before the `*`.

Thus, `^/[^r/obts]*\.txt$` will match any text documents in the root that have any number (including 0) of any characters except [r,/,o,b,t,s] ending in `.txt`, for instance `/zzzfile.txt` but not `/mysecretfile.txt`, because that contains both `r` and `t` and `s`. It also doesn't match `/xyz/xyz.txt`, due to the `/` inside the brackets.
This is closer to what you tried to do, but it doesn't exclude just `/robots.txt`, which is what you want.

`^/[^r/][^o/][^b/][^o/][^t/][^s/]\.txt$` matches any 6-characters except robots (plus .txt extension).

Comment: I tried to add those lines under my existing ErrorDocument 404 /error_file.php, and all the txt files are still accessible. The lines I added:
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ robots.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^/[^/]*\.txt$ [L,R=404]

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On`? (and robots.real as the substitution, not .txt)

Comment: RewriteEngine is On, I tried to put the lines you wrote beneath it and also above it. should I change the name of my robots.txt file to another name? I'm not sure I understood what you meant.

Comment: Yes, i meant to rename the robots.txt to something not ending in .txt and rewrite robots.txt to get that file instead and after that is done, rewrite all root-directory .txt to something that fails. A good idea is to start out small and make sure the techniques are working as expected. Try to determine if rewriting is working at all for starters. For instance `RewriteRule /foobar /robots.txt [L]` and try to fetch /foobar to see if you get the robots.txt contents.

Comment: It seems like the rewriting isn't working at all with '        RewriteRule /foobar /robots.txt [L]' - Other RewriteRules are working (Such as access the site with WWW prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Removing those file will have the same effect as far as HTTP clients are concerned, and will be probably easier.